# Is HierarchicalLifetimeManager the correct lifetime manager to use for WCF client / ChannelFactory

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, object-lifetime

I have a very simple WPF application that is calling

There is one container for the application, that is configured when the application starts.

The WPF app has a service reference to my WCF service.
I have registered my generated proxy to the container like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IAccountService>(
    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => new ChannelFactory<IAccountService>("endpoint_name")
    .CreateChannel()));
```

My question is, is using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` the correct choice for a WPF application that calls the WCF service whenever a user interacts with the UI? *(fills in a text box and presses search)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, but not for the channels.

Creating [`ChannelFactory<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132(v=vs.110).aspx) objects is an *expensive* operation, since that's where a lot of the initialization happens, compared to creating the actual channels.

The general rule of thumb is to *reuse* `ChannelFactory<T>` instances (they're also *thread-safe*) while treating the channels as *disposable*. In fact, the generated proxies based on `ClientBase<T>` also cache the channel factory internally [to improve performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx).

When creating these objects through a DI container, it's advisable to configure the `ChannelFactory<T>` as *singleton* and the channels as *transient*:

```
container.RegisterInstance(
    new ChannelFactory<IAccountService>("endpointName"),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IAccountService>(
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
        c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IAccountService>>().CreateChannel()));
```

Comment: slightly outside the scope of this question, but in a web application, would I register the `.CreateChannel` as once per request? to handle faulted channels etc...? - ie, `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`

Comment: For a web app that uses Unity I'd configure both the `ChannelFactory<T>` _and_ the channels with either the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` or the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`, since those are [the only built-in lifetime managers that automatically dispose](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/) the objects they create upon release. Alternatively, you could write your own [lifetime manager per HTTP request](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/03/unity-and-http-per-request-lifetime.html) that also does the dispose on release.